# Deep learning not classify some classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data

I want to classify 13 classes, but 2 classes is not classified.
This is the test result.
As you can see in the image, class 3 and class 11 is not detected.
It's simple vector to class classification.
The dimension of input is 16 and I've added 2 dense layers in the model.
What do I need to add to model?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context for the problem. Are your classes ordered or are they independent? Are you passing the label as an integer or is it one-hot encoded? I'm asking these questions because from what I can see, for example for class no. 3, your model is predicting the nearest classes (i.e. 2 and 4).

Comment: You can't always assume that your results would lead to 100% accuracy. With no context, I can only suspect that the differentiation between those 2 particular classes, with all other classes, is weak. Also, maybe they are minority classes and your model is ignoring them. You need to provide some more insight into your data.

Comment: the classes are ordered, and label is one-hot encoded.

Comment: Here's the link of data https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4ea6t7m102b0j8/person1_2_3_EEG_set1.zip?dl=0

Comment: Hmm, I added one more layer and now the accuracy is 100%. I'm not sure the result is correct.